# Generating a PLIST file - to be read by Objective-C - via PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, xml, plist

The title sums it up. Would that be possible, as in, is the data structure of a PLIST file possible to generate efficiently via PHP for an Objective-C app to read? Or, would a different format like XML be better?

I'm more keen to go with PLIST as I hear it's easier to parse from Obj-C, and won't require any external libraries (this is for an iPhone app, not Mac - where I'd just use NSXMLParser or whatever it's called).

Comment: plist files *are* XML files (unless they're compressed binary plists of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's possible. [The `plist` format is well-documented](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2). Further more, one of the representations is in XML format.

You may want to use this library: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList

Comment: CFPropertylist was just what I was looking for! Thanks, Kenny :)